# "Invalid param: could not find account" when using solana.py to call solana RPC API function

Tags: jsonrpc-api, python, solana-py

I need some help with solana.py API (for python).
I am trying to get total supply of the token ([token here](https://explorer.solana.com/address/CUSDvqAQLbt7fRofcmV2EXfPA2t36kzj7FjzdmqDiNQL)) - so I copy mint address according to documentation ([gettokensupply](https://docs.solana.com/ru/api/http#gettokensupply)) and write usual code on solana==0.25.1:

```
 from solana.rpc.api import Client
 from solana.publickey import PublicKey
 http_client_solana = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
 pubkey = PublicKey("CxwTQccajoiDn9Xb7BpTbvDQXEaSKNYQWMCUETiNgidZ")
 response = http_client_solana.get_token_supply(pubkey)

 amount = int(response["result"]['value']['amount'])
 decimals = response["result"]['value']['decimals']
```

But I receive a `response`:

`{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'Invalid param: could not find account'}, 'id': 1}`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, is it a problem on my end? I tried using it also with a coin address, but I still get the same error. I checked if I used exactly the mint and tried to call it using mentioned address in the example, but still receive the same error. I tried researching the problem, but found no hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the devnet url to mainnet. That is, change https://api.devnet.solana.com to https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

Comment: I appreciate your help! It was the problem indeed, now it is solved.
One colleague mentioned on the community server, that Devnet is a testnet (I assume, it's a net for tests), but we are trying to get an address from mainnet => we must use mainnet URL.
P.S.-The credits for advice go to someone named 'Raliphey'.

Comment: Solana also has something it calls testnet but it's mainly for validators to test stuff. But yes both devnet and testnet are not real money https://docs.solana.com/clusters